# Android Studio doesn't show x86_64 as option for any virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

I'm very new to Android development. I've just downloaded Android Studio and and starting my first app. I'm trying to use the **Virtual Device Manager** to create a new virtual device. The tutorial I am following is telling me to pick a device with an **`x86_64`** architecture. Having picked the Nexus 5x phone, there is no option for any **`x86_64`** images.

I see the different API levels as options, but they are all `x86`.

Why might this be?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to select very next tab i.e x86 Images to generate  **x86_64 images**. check below image

[image]

Comment: Well that's embarrassing... :'D

Comment: I don't think it's embarrassing.... happened to me as well. I feel like it's a UX issue.